# Failure delivering result error when I click on the bluetooth device found on second activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

I created this app based on Bluetooth chat example and Bluetooth viewer .
Here is the code that start second activity  to found bluetooth devices:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search :
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, StartScan.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_START_SCAN);       
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
    }
```

and here is my second activity that scan for devices:

```
public class StartScan extends Activity {
    //Debugging 
    public static final String TAG = "StartScan";
    public static final boolean D = true;

    //Return intent extra
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    //Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter ; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREAT +++");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_scan);
        //Set result canceled in case the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        //Initialize the button to perform device discovery
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startScan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                doDiscovery();
            }
        });
        //Initialize the button to perform cancel discovery     
        Button cancelScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelScan);
        cancelScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        //Initialize ArrayAdapter for newly discovered devices
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.device_name);   
        //Find and setup list view for newly discovered devices
        ListView newDevivesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        newDevivesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevivesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for Broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        //Register for Broadcasts when discovery is finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        //Get the local bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
        //Make sure we are not doing discovery any more
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }   
        //Unregister broadcast listener
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
     /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery(){
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "DO DISCOVERY");
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();
        //turn on subtitle for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //If we are already discovering , cancel it
        if(mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        //Request discover from bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    //The on click listener for all devices in the list view
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3){
        //Cancel discovery because  it is costly and we are about to connect
        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        //Get the device MAC address , which is the last 17 chars in the view
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        //Create the result intent and include MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "... PUT EXTRA ...");
        //Set result and finish this activity
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, ".. SET RESULT ..");
        finish();
        }
    }; 
    //The broadcast receiver that listens for discovered devices and changes the title when discovery is finished
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
            String action = intent.getAction();

            //When discovery finds a device 
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            //Get the bluetooth device object from the intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
            //When discovery is finished , changed the activity title
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0){
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start_scan, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

after I click on a device its stop from working .
you can see my app's log here:

```
09-10 01:25:40.692: E/MainActivity(26328): +++ ON CREATE +++
09-10 01:25:40.872: E/MainActivity(26328): ++ ON START ++
09-10 01:25:40.922: E/MainActivity(26328): + ON RESUME +
09-10 01:25:40.962: E/MainActivity(26328): - ON PAUSE -
09-10 01:25:41.062: D/libEGL(26328): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-10 01:25:41.102: D/libEGL(26328): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-10 01:25:41.152: D/libEGL(26328): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-10 01:25:41.152: D/libEGL(26328): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-10 01:25:41.333: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(26328): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-10 01:25:41.353: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5217e000 size:1536000 fd:63
09-10 01:25:41.393: D/OpenGLRenderer(26328): Enabling debug mode 0
09-10 01:25:41.533: D/OpenGLRenderer(26328): has fontRender patch
09-10 01:25:41.603: D/OpenGLRenderer(26328): has fontRender patch
09-10 01:25:41.643: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x527bb000 size:1536000 fd:66
09-10 01:25:47.569: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52a32000 size:1536000 fd:69
09-10 01:25:47.569: D/MainActivity(26328): onActivityResult -1
09-10 01:25:47.579: E/MainActivity(26328): + ON RESUME +
09-10 01:25:50.572: E/MainActivity(26328): - ON PAUSE -
09-10 01:25:50.582: E/StartScan(26328): +++ ON CREAT +++
09-10 01:25:50.682: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(26328): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-10 01:25:50.692: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52e20000 size:1536000 fd:73
09-10 01:25:50.762: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5310e000 size:1536000 fd:79
09-10 01:25:50.772: D/OpenGLRenderer(26328): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-10 01:25:50.992: E/MainActivity(26328): -- ON STOP --
09-10 01:25:53.454: D/memalloc(26328): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5217e000 size:1536000 fd:64
09-10 01:25:53.594: D/StartScan(26328): DO DISCOVERY
09-10 01:25:55.727: D/StartScan(26328): ... PUT EXTRA ...
09-10 01:25:55.727: D/StartScan(26328): .. SET RESULT ..
09-10 01:25:55.777: D/MainActivity(26328): onActivityResult -1
09-10 01:25:55.797: D/AndroidRuntime(26328): Shutting down VM
09-10 01:25:55.797: W/dalvikvm(26328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acd228)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.atrin/com.example.atrin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3387)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3437)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1291)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at com.example.atrin.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:172)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4740)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3383)
09-10 01:25:55.817: E/AndroidRuntime(26328):    ... 11 more
09-10 01:25:58.249: D/Process(26328): killProcess, pid=26328
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
09-10 01:25:58.269: D/Process(26328): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 01:25:58.269: I/Process(26328): Sending signal. PID: 26328 SIG: 9
09-10 01:52:55.337: E/MainActivity(26553): +++ ON CREATE +++
09-10 01:52:55.447: E/MainActivity(26553): ++ ON START ++
09-10 01:52:55.477: E/MainActivity(26553): + ON RESUME +
09-10 01:52:55.527: D/libEGL(26553): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-10 01:52:55.537: D/libEGL(26553): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-10 01:52:55.547: D/libEGL(26553): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-10 01:52:55.547: D/libEGL(26553): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-10 01:52:55.607: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(26553): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-10 01:52:55.637: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5217e000 size:1536000 fd:63
09-10 01:52:55.657: D/OpenGLRenderer(26553): Enabling debug mode 0
09-10 01:52:55.957: D/OpenGLRenderer(26553): has fontRender patch
09-10 01:52:55.997: D/OpenGLRenderer(26553): has fontRender patch
09-10 01:52:56.027: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x527bb000 size:1536000 fd:66
09-10 01:52:56.908: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52a32000 size:1536000 fd:69
09-10 01:52:56.978: E/MainActivity(26553): - ON PAUSE -
09-10 01:52:56.988: E/StartScan(26553): +++ ON CREAT +++
09-10 01:52:57.078: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(26553): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-10 01:52:57.088: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52e20000 size:1536000 fd:73
09-10 01:52:57.158: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5310e000 size:1536000 fd:79
09-10 01:52:57.168: D/OpenGLRenderer(26553): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-10 01:52:57.389: E/MainActivity(26553): -- ON STOP --
09-10 01:52:57.899: D/memalloc(26553): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5217e000 size:1536000 fd:64
09-10 01:52:57.969: D/StartScan(26553): DO DISCOVERY
09-10 01:52:59.891: D/StartScan(26553): ... PUT EXTRA ...
09-10 01:52:59.891: D/StartScan(26553): .. SET RESULT ..
09-10 01:52:59.931: D/MainActivity(26553): onActivityResult -1
09-10 01:52:59.951: D/AndroidRuntime(26553): Shutting down VM
09-10 01:52:59.951: W/dalvikvm(26553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acd228)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.atrin/com.example.atrin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3387)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3437)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1291)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.example.atrin.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:172)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4740)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3383)
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    
09-10 01:52:59.961: E/AndroidRuntime(26553):    at com.example.atrin.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:172)
```

You have a null pointer at `line 172` in your `com.example.atrin.MainActivity`.

Please post your code from that line, to see the problem.